# How to get the minimum and maximum date and grouped it by id

Tags: javascript

I have this array of data

```
[{"id":1, "start":"2018-10-10", "end":"2018-11-10"},
 {"id":1, "start":"2018-11-10", "end":"2018-12-10"},
 {"id":2, "start":"2018-11-22", "end":"2018-11-30"}]
```

I wanted to get the `minimum` in the start and the `maximum` in the end.

My desired output would be

```
{"id":1, "start":"2018-10-10", "end":"2018-12-10"},
{"id":2, "start":"2018-11-22", "end":"2018-11-30"}
```

I tried doing like this:

```
data.sort((a,b) => a.start.toString().localeCompare(b.start))
```

Comment: There is zero jQuery in your question. Also, none of the objects have a `start_date` property, and you don't have to call `toString()` on something that's already a string.

Comment: I thought sort is jquery sorry

Comment: why haven't you used any of the grouping code you got in the question you asked 2 hours ago? Stackoverflow is not a free code writing service. People will happily help but we aren't here to do all the work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do will require a custom solution where you merge two entries. In the below function I have iterated your array in chunks of same id first I have sorted it based on id and kept a min and max of the index where your logic says on date

```js
function groupById(arr){
  arr.sort((a,b)=>a.id-b.id);
  let arrNew = [];
  let min=0, max=0, currentid = arr[0].id;
  for(i=1; i<arr.length+1;i++){
    if(!arr[i] || arr[i].id!=currentid){
      arrNew.push({id:currentid, start:arr[min].start, end: arr[max].end});
      min = i;max=i;currentid=(arr[i]||{}).id;
    }
    if(!arr[i]){
      break;
    }
    if(arr[i].start<arr[min].start){
      min = i;
    }
    if(arr[i].end>arr[max].end){
      max = i;
    }
  }
  return arrNew;
}

var result = groupById([
  {"id":1, "start":"2018-10-10", "end":"2018-11-10"},
  {"id":1, "start":"2018-11-10", "end":"2018-12-10"},
  {"id":2, "start":"2018-11-22", "end":"2018-11-30"}
]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to sort array using date comparison and also [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) it by id.

```
var data = [{
    "id": 1,
    "start": "2018-10-10",
    "end": "2018-11-10"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "start": "2018-11-10",
    "end": "2018-12-10"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "start": "2018-11-22",
    "end": "2018-11-30"
  }
];


let result = data.sort((a, b) => new Date(a.start) > new Date(b.start)).reduce(function(r, a) {
  if (!r[a.id] || r[a.id][0].id !== a.id) {
    r[a.id] = r[a.id] || [];
    r[a.id].push(a);
  }

  return r;
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be having multiple things that need to be grouped and reduces (as shown by comment referring to other question). So I will provide some general methods in this answer.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) has excelent documentation on all methods used here like map, reduce and Object.value, I would advice you have a look there to understand the code better.

ES6 syntax is explained very well [here](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/es6%20%26%20beyond/ch2.md)

```js
const data = [
  { id: 1, start: '2018-10-10', end: '2018-11-10' },
  { id: 1, start: '2018-11-10', end: '2018-12-10' },
  { id: 2, start: '2018-11-22', end: '2018-11-30' },
];

const groupBy = (arr, key) =>
  arr.reduce(
    (result, item) => (
      result[item[key]].push(item), result
    ),
    arr.reduce(
      (result, item) => ((result[item[key]] = []), result),
      {},
    ),
  );
const returnLowHigh = (comp) => (a, b) =>
  a.localeCompare(b) === comp ? a : b;
const lowest = returnLowHigh(-1);
const highest = returnLowHigh(1);
console.log(
  Object.values(groupBy(data, 'id')).map((items) =>
    items.reduce((result, { id, start, end }) => ({
      id,
      start: lowest(result.start, start),
      end: highest(result.end, end),
    })),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce function and check the start and end date and if start date

```js
let old = [{
    "id": 1,
    "start": "2018-10-10",
    "end": "2018-11-10"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "start": "2018-11-10",
    "end": "2018-12-10"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "start": "2018-11-22",
    "end": "2018-11-30"
  }
];

let k = old.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  let findId = acc.findIndex((item) => {
    return item.id === curr.id
  });

  if (findId === -1) {
    acc.push(curr)
  } else {
    let oldStartDate = createDate(acc[findId].start);
    let newStartDate = createDate(curr.start);
    let oldEndDate = createDate(acc[findId].end);
    let newEndDate = createDate(curr.end);


    if (newStartDate < oldStartDate) {

      acc[findId].start = curr.start
    }
    if (newEndDate > oldEndDate) {

      acc[findId].end = curr.end
    }

  }

  return acc;

}, []);

console.log(k);

function createDate(dte) {
  let dt = new Date(dte);
  return `${dt.getYear()}-${dt.getMonth()}-${dt.getDate()}`

}
```